# Rest-Assured JIRA Java unable to get Response

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, rest-assured

Please consider below code,

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.omg.CORBA.Request;

import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class App 
{

    @Test
    public void loginAuthentication()
    {

        RestAssured.authentication = basic("username", "password");

        Response resp = given().
            contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").
        when().
            post("https://unitrends.atlassian.net/login?username=Gayatri.londhe&password=GayatriA4");

        System.out.println(resp.prettyPrint());
    }
}
```

I am getting below response,

```
<div class="aui-message error">
     <span class="aui-icon icon-error"/>
     <span class="error" id="error-authentication_failure_invalid_credentials">
        Sorry, we didn't recognize that username and password combination. Please double-check and try again.
     </span>
</div>
```

---

How to use authentication in rest-assured, i am able to do rest post request using REST-console (chrome plugin).
What am i doing wrong?

I hope to get some help at this. I am new at rest-assured testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Response resp = given().
            contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").expect().response().statusCode(200).
            when().
            post("https://unitrends.atlassian.net/login?username=Gayatri.londhe&password=GayatriA4");
```

It will fetch response if the response status is 200.Change it,if you service endpoint returns other than 200 on success.

Try this

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() throws org.json.JSONException, IOException {
  //Assigning base url
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://unitrends.atlassian.net/";
    //Assigning default port
    RestAssured.port = <port>
    RestAssured.basePath = "login";
    RestAssured.config = config().redirect(RedirectConfig.redirectConfig().followRedirects(true).and().allowCircularRedirects(true).maxRedirects(100));
}
@Test
public void testRestServiceAuthentication() {
    //for a get method with basic authorization,its expecting response code 200
    Response res = given().expect().response().statusCode(200).when().post("?username=Gayatri.londhe&password=GayatriA4");
    System.out.println(res.getBody().asString());
}
```

Comment: the test ran successfully, 
i want to extract atl_Token from the response. how can i do that?

Comment: and why is it that i dont see this api hit on fiddler?

Comment: `String output = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println(output);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
        String status= String.valueOf(obj.get("<atl_Token>"));
    }
`
You can use this..Is that token is send as header ?

Comment: I am using "com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured" this jar

Comment: Your server running in local machine or remote machine?If remote machine make sure that firewall is off.
Have you hit the endpoint with any rest client?Is it okey to share you endpoint?If so i could try to find the cause.

Comment: we are using JIRA Cloud, not JIRA Server or client.

Comment: Then it suppose to work.As i told if you can share the details, it could be helpful for me to analyse.

Comment: I can post api hit Using postman. my main query is how to do the same using rest-assured. 

http://i.imgur.com/6G6JEO0.png

Comment: i have updated the code above in answer section.Check that out.

Comment: cant get to import APIPortalCommonProperties in maven, can you please help me with the same? and can you please tell why port is necessary?

Comment: No no.I have copied from some other file by mistake.If you have more servers running in one machine, then you how will you redirect the requests.So,when ever you request some service, it will be redirected based on that.

Comment: okay, i understand that, but the JIRA we are using is JIRA Cloud, it it does no require port assignment for requests.

Comment: As far as i heard,While configuring the cloud server, you will map the domain(in your case - unitrends.atlassian.net) with the host & port.